# Using automator to run a shell script when I right click an image in OSX

Tags: macos, automator

I'm trying to figure out how to use automator to do this but keep getting errors and I don't understand what the problem is.

[image: Screenshot of what I'm trying to do!]

Comment: Try putting the full path to `mogrify` instead of plain `mogrify`. Try putting double quotes around the parameter... `mogrify ... "$1"`

Comment: Try `-resize '640'` without the *x*. The *x* is allowed to use as width wildcard when using a given height as in `-resize 'x480'`. Use single quotes for the resize parameter!